# Invoke Control with BackGroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, singleton, invoke

Have strange problem and can't figure out with it.

Trying to transform an RichTextBox to a log 'console' in my application. Of course I use threads in my application, and of course I know about Invoke.

Let's take a look at my code.

`MainForm` starts a `BackGroundWorker` to do the work. My `BackGroundWorker` starts a lot of threads that call `DebugConsole` at event. For this question I make a simple example.

```
bkw.DoWork += (obj, a) => DebugConsole.DoSomeWork(msg, Color.Coral);
bkw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

`DebugConsole` is a class where I implement a singleton pattern to get my `DoSomeWork` function.

Let's look at `DebugConsole` class:

```
class DebugConsole
{
        private static readonly DebugConsole instance = new DebugConsole();

        public static DebugConsole Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }

        public static void DoSomeWork(string msg, Color color)
        {
            Instance.DebugBox(msg, color);
        }

        private void DebugBox(string msg, Color color)
        {
            MainForm.DoSomeWork(msg, color);
        }
    }
```

And as well you see my `MainForm` also has singleton pattern implemented that call the next think.

```
private static readonly MainForm instance = new MainForm();

public static MainForm Instance
{
    get { return instance; }
}

public static void DoSomeWork(string ev, Color clr)
{
    Instance.LogTextEvent(ev,clr);
}
```

`LogTextEvent` do the last think in my application, it writes a message in my RichTextBox, and this is the problem. It doesn't write/invoke my control.

```
public void LogTextEvent(string eventText, Color textColor)
{
        var nDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt") + " - ";
        if (rtbDebug.InvokeRequired)
        {
            rtbDebug.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                rtbDebug.SelectionStart = rtbDebug.Text.Length;
                rtbDebug.SelectionColor = textColor;

                if (rtbDebug.Lines.Length == 0)
                {
                    rtbDebug.AppendText(nDateTime + eventText);
                    rtbDebug.ScrollToCaret();
                    rtbDebug.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    rtbDebug.AppendText(nDateTime 
                                      + eventText 
                                      + Environment.NewLine);
                    rtbDebug.ScrollToCaret();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            rtbDebug.SelectionStart = rtbDebug.Text.Length;
            rtbDebug.SelectionColor = textColor;

            if (rtbDebug.Lines.Length == 0)
            {
                rtbDebug.AppendText(nDateTime + eventText);
                rtbDebug.ScrollToCaret();
                rtbDebug.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                rtbDebug.AppendText(nDateTime 
                                  + eventText 
                                  + Environment.NewLine);
                rtbDebug.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem: nothing happens in my control.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Can somebody tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Have you used the Visual Studio debugger to find out what code is actually executed?

Comment: Of course I use VS to debug that... all the code seems to work fine

Comment: Given: your code fails to do what you want, and when you debug it seems to be doing what you want, it must be the case that you have failed to correctly debug the problem (i.e. misused the debugger, thereby failing to identify the bug). Of course, no one else can do any debugging on your behalf without a complete code example. The biggest issue I see in the code you posted is the copy/paste for invoking. But there's nothing in this case that suggests the actual problem. You'll either need to [improve the code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or improve your debugging. :)

Comment: You are probably fire-hosing the UI thread with too many BeginInvoke() calls.  You'll see it burning 100% core, trying to keep up but not succeeding at it.  It stops taking care of the lower priority tasks, like painting.  Beyond reducing the BeginInvoke call rate, it is also *very* important to limit the amount of text in the RTB.  Those AppendText() calls get very expensive after a while.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
             Instance.LogTextEvent(ev,clr);
        });
```

Comment: The implementation of `LogTextEvent` marshals to the UI thread for its implementation.